# Show that function is integrable in $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let's inspect the function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (-1)^{k}, & \mbox{if } x \in (\frac{k-1}{k},\frac{k}{k+1}]\mbox{ for some k} \in \mathbb{N} \\ 0, & \mbox{if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

Is $f$ integrable in $[0,1]$?

My idea is to use the basic knowledge of integration such as:

If bounded function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has only finite number of points of discontinuity, then $f$ is integrable.

Still I am not sure how to use that fact of basic knowledge to solve the task. I have an exam in three days so any explanations and help will be greatly appreciated.

Hopefully it helps me to understand basic pirinciples better and return the favour for the community in the future :).

Comment: That fact won't help here, because it's discontinuous at $\{1-1/k \,| \, k \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$, which is not a finite set. I think you should use Riemann or Darboux sums.

Comment: Prove the more general theorem: let $D$ be the set of discontinuities of a bounded function $f$ on an interval $[a, b] $. If $D$ has a finite number of limit points then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $. The proof is similar to the case when $D$ is a finite set. Also this does not involve measure theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Here is the full argument without using Lebesgue Criterion

I am using following theorem to show your function is integrable.Following theorem is easy to prove.

> $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, and $f$ is integrable on $[a, c]$ for all  $ c \in$
>   $(a, b)$, then f is integrable on $[a, b]$.

*proof :*

1)pick arbitrary $x<1$ we know that there is $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $x <\frac{k+1}{k} <1$ because $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{k+1}{k} =1$

2)Now we know that there atmost finite number of discontinuities on $[0, \frac{k}{k+1}]$ hence your function is integrable on $[0, \frac{k}{k+1}]$

3)Since this holds for arbitrary $x$ we can say that function is integrable on interval $[0,x]$ for any $x<1$

4)use above theorem to conclude that function is integrable  on $[0,1]$

Moreover, Since you have that function is integrable, We can now calculate it's value.Specifically we can show that

$$\int_{0}^1 f = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{\frac{k-1}{k}}^{\frac{k}{k+1}} f $$

---

Function can be discontinuous *atmost* at each interval point. So,Your function has atmost countably infinite number of discontinuities.

> let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded .If set of discontinuities has measure zero , Then function is Riemann Integrable

In your case set of discontinuities has measure $0$. Hence your function is Riemann Integrable

Comment: I think this answer is not helpful, because you are using Lebesgue's criterion, which is far more advanced.

Comment: @Botond added a  argument without lebesgue's criterion

Comment: Nice, it looks good :) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

We can write $f$ as a sum of characteristic functions:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} (-1)^{k}, & \mbox{if } x \in (\frac{k-1}{k},\frac{k}{k+1}]\mbox{ for some }k \in \mathbb{N}^+ \\ 0, & \mbox{if } x=0 \end{cases}$$
$$
=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \chi_{((k-1)/k,k/(k+1)]}(x)
$$Then we have
$$
\int _0^1\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \chi_{((k-1)/k,k/(k+1)]}(x)
 \,dx= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \left(\frac{k}{k+1}-\frac{k-1}{k}\right)
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k(k+1)}
$$This series converges, so $f$ is integrable. Ms. Alpha gives an exact value of $1-\log(4)$.

Comment: And how do you justify the swapping of the integral and the sum?

Comment: Fix $1>\varepsilon>0$. On $[0,1-\varepsilon/2)$, $f$ can be written as a finite sum of characteristic functions and on $[1-\varepsilon/2,1]$, $|f|\leq 2$, so the total error can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: I think it works :) (+1)